# STL function to get all dimensions of a vector in c++

Tags: c++

I wish to know if there is any STL function in c++, to get the dimensions of a vector.
For example,
vec = [[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6]]
The dimensions are **(2, 3)**

I am aware of *size()* function. But the function does not return dimensions.

In the above example, vec.size() would have returned 2.
To get second dimension, I would have to use vec[0].size(), which would be 3

Comment: A `std::vector` only ever has 1 dimension. Any *nested* vectors will each have their own (single, unique) dimension.

Comment: What should be the reported dimensions for `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [], [6, 7, 8, 9]]`?

Comment: Thanks everyone!
I get the point now. Asking for all dimensions of n-D vector does not make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, a(n `std::`)`vector` is, by definition, 1D-vector of `size()` elements, which can be changed in runtime.

You can define a vector of vectors (e.g., `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`), but that doesn't have a constraint that the 'inner' dimensions are the same. E.g., `{{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}}` is valid.

Therefore, inner dimensions are ambiguous. What you can do, if you maintain it to be the same *and* if you're sure that you've got elements, is to query `v[0].size()` as well, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [lorro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74000824/15261315), you likely want to find the dimensions of a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Finding the outer dimension is easy, since all you have to do is `vec.size()`. But the inner vectors can be of any length, and don't have to be the same length. Assuming you want the minimum, this is doable with STL functions.

We can use `std::transform` to fill a vector with the dimensions of the inner vectors, and then use `std::min_element` to find the smaller of those.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec = {{1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}};

  std::vector<std::size_t> dim(vec.size());

  std::transform(vec.cbegin(), vec.cend(), dim.begin(),
                 [](auto &v) { return v.size(); });

  std::size_t min = *std::min_element(dim.cbegin(), dim.cend()); 

  std::cout << "(" << vec.size() << ", " << min << ")\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(2, 2)
```